How to find offsets of Vector2's give number of points row, amount of points, and centered vertically?
Say that I want to make a grid that contains 5 points and up to 3 points on each row. starting from the top I should have 3 points followed by 2 points underneath centered by the same distance like so:

Similarly if I had 9 points and wanted to fit them in rows of 4 I would get rows of 4, 4, 1:

How would one make such? I did find that for row to row spacing, or for the y, something like: "floor((x-1)/w)-(ceil(n/w)-1)/2" works, where n is the number of points, x being the point, and w being the amount of points in a row.
